# Multithreaded socket gets closed before remote script execution over

Tags: python

Using Python 2.6.6, I am not able to get complete data from client script as suspecting the socket gets closed before the client script execution is over, while the client script working fine if I manually trigger the script on the remote server.

What script does -

**Trigger SCRIPT**

Only to transfer the client script [agent.py] and trigger remotely using multithread.

**Client SCRIPT**

- agent.py would be transferred to target servers [1000+]
- running on (1000+) remote servers [linux] to collect data and return
  a list of dictionary from each remote machine back to Server

**Server SCRIPT**

- Receives the data and convert to CSV

**Client Script - agent.py**

```
 s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
 host = "<SERVER_HOST>"          # server ip
 port = 12345                    # Reserve a port for your service.
 try:
    s.connect((host, port))
    instlist = []
    infoCollect = processInfo()  #get the info in dictionary object
    instlist.append(infoCollect)
    data_string = str(instlist)
    s.sendall(data_string)
    s.send(",")
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print('Sent ',(instlist))
    s.close()
```

**Server Script [DataCollector]:**

```
class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        print 'Started Listening....'
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            print 'Got connection from', address
            client.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        while True:
           try:
              l = client.recv(size)
              while (l):
                 print ("Receiving...%s" % l)
                 f.write(l)
                 l = client.recv(size)
                 print "Instance Details Recieved"
              client.send('Thank you for connecting')

           except:
                client.close()
                return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        port_num = input("Port? ")
        try:
            port_num = int(port_num)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    f = open(array_data,'wb')
    ThreadedServer('',port_num).listen()
```

**Trigger Script** -  This script's purpose is to initiate this all process and place the Client Script [agentScript] on 1000+ servers and execute remotely

```
 cmd = "python agent.py"

 takeLock = threading.Lock()

 def worker(host):
     ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() # Initiate SSH Object
     ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
     try:
        ssh.connect(host, username='user', password='pass' )

        sftp = ssh.open_sftp()   #sedning files to parellaly to all listed servers
        sftp.put(__file__, 'excludelist')
        sftp.close()

        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
           # Print Only data when available
           if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
              alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
              prevdata = b"1"
              while prevdata:
                prevdata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                alldata += prevdata
                print alldata
              return (str(alldata))
        ssh.close()

     except socket.error, v:
           print "Connection Refused"

 def main():

     with open('IPlist.txt') as ip:
         hosts = ip.read().splitlines()

     threads = []
     for h in hosts:
         t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(h,))
         t.start()
         threads.append(t)
     for t in threads:
         t.join()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

> NOTE: Client Script [agent.py] takes 1-5 sec depends on the server's
>   configuration to generate output and return value

PROBLEM - Incomplete Data populating at server side like -

When I trigger script manually on remote machine to test it send complete dictionary object like [{commonServerData},{a,b,c,d},{Engine02Data},{tempData,tempData02}] and so server recives the same data

When agent.py is invoked using trigger script it sends incomplete data like-
[{commonServerData},{a,b,c,d}] for all 1000+ srervers.

I am suspecting something wrong with my Trigger Script which does close the socket session of the remote server even before the agent.py gets completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed extra comma `s.send(',')` and added it to `s.sendall(data_string + ',')` from the client script does the expected work -

```
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
 host = "<SERVER_HOST>"          # server ip
 port = 12345                    # Reserve a port for your service.
 try:
    s.connect((host, port))
    instlist = []
    infoCollect = processInfo()  #get the info in dictionary object
    instlist.append(infoCollect)
    data_string = str(instlist)
    s.sendall(data_string + ',')
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print('Sent ',(instlist))
    s.close()
```